# How to re-add a mediasource after the exoplayer has been prepared?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm creating a playlist video player in exoplayer in android studio. I'm adding the first video extracted from a server and it is being played by the exoplayer perfectly. But when I add the second part, the exoplayer does not play that video. I want to add the second video after the exoplayer has been prepared. I want to know how to do that. Please Help me.

My `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    SimpleExoPlayer video_player;
    PlayerView player_screen;
    DefaultTrackSelector track_selector;
    DefaultBandwidthMeter band_width_meter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    ArrayList<MediaSource> mediaSources_contents = new ArrayList<>();
    ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenating_mediaSource_contents;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        player_screen = (PlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_screen);
        player_screen.requestFocus();

        TrackSelection.Factory video_track_selection_factory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(band_width_meter);
        track_selector = new DefaultTrackSelector(video_track_selection_factory);
        video_player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, track_selector);

        player_screen.setPlayer(video_player);
        video_player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        Uri url1 = Uri.parse("THE - URL - OF - FIRST - VIDEO");
        DataSource.Factory data_source_factory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "Application Name"), band_width_meter);
        MediaSource source1 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(data_source_factory).createMediaSource(url1);
        mediaSources_contents.add(source1);

        concatenating_mediaSource_contents = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources_contents.toArray(new MediaSource[mediaSources_contents.size()]));
        video_player.prepare(concatenating_mediaSource_contents);

        // The lines below this point adds the second video to the media source. But it is not being played by the exoplayer.

        Uri url2 = Uri.parse("THE - URL - OF - SECOND - VIDEO");
        MediaSource source2 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(data_source_factory).createMediaSource(url2);
        mediaSources_contents.add(source2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### At Prepared Time

**Initialize `ConcatenatingMediaSource`**
`ConcatenatingMediaSource mediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();`

```
 MediaSource firstSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new FileDataSourceFactory()).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(uri.get(0)));
 MediaSource secondSource= new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new FileDataSourceFactory()).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(uri.get(1)));
 mediaSource.addMediaSources(firstSource);
 mediaSource.addMediaSources(secondSource);
 player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
```

### After Prepare Add `mediasource`

```
 MediaSource thirdSource= new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new FileDataSourceFactory()).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(uri.get(3)));
 mediaSource.addMediaSources(thirdSource);// mediaSource is refrance of ConcatenatingMediaSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this `concatenating_mediaSource_contents.addMediaSource(source2);` instead `mediaSources_contents.add(source2);`and for first media source also (not necessary, for better readability)